# How to float image right without footer popping to the top and background colour disappearing

Tags: html, css

i know this is very basic but can't seem to wrap my head around it. I am trying to float an image to the right of the text, each time i do that, the image actually floats to the right but then, the footer pops to the top and the white background colour disappears. I have spend surprisingly two days trying to resolve this embarrassing error but no result. Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <title> Learninghub </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slide2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-slideshow-styles.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class = "body">
           <div class = "header">
                                <div class = "wrapper">

                                             <div class = "left">
                                                <a href ="http://pac-center.com/#/ms-23/1">
                                                        <img src = "images/learninghub.png" width = "406" height = "75" alt" The learninghub and paccenter logo ">
                                                </a>
                                             </div>




                                          <div class = "right">

                                            <img src = "images/call.png" width = "15" height = "15" alt " call icon">
                                            <div class = "today">
                                                 <small>Call us today</small></br> 
                                                 <strong>09-2921465</strong>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class = "right_2">

                                                 <img src = "images/location.png" width = "10" height = "15" alt " location icon">

                                                  <div class = " right_1">
                                                    <a href = "https://www.google.com.ng/maps">
                                                        <small>Suite 1, Capital Hub Mall, Plot 272 Ahmadu Bello Way</small></br>
                                                        <strong> Along Wuse-Gwarinpa-Next Express Way, F.C.T Abuja.</strong></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                  </div>



                                          </div>


                                </div>


                 </div>


                 <nav>
                                            <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
                                            <ul class="menu">
                                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                                                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">About Us +</label>
                                                    <a href="About us.html">About Us</a>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="methodology.html">Methodology</a></li>

                                                    </ul> 

                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="service.html">Services</a></li>
                                                <li>

                                                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                                                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">List of Courses +</label>
                                                <a href="#">List of Courses</a>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="administration.html">Administration</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="agriculture.html">Agriculture</a></li>


                                                </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>

                                                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                                                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Ongoing Courses +</label>
                                                <a href="#">Ongoing Courses</a>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                                                <ul>


                                                    <li><a href="creative.html">Creative</a></li>
                                                     <li><a href="enterprise.html">Enterprise</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="excel.html">Microsoft Excel</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="Hardware.html">Hardware</a></li>
                                                     <li><a href="management.html">MIS</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="microsoft_office.html">Microsoft Office</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="networking.html">Networking</a></li>
                                                     <li><a href="webdesign.html">Web Design</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="webdev.html">Web Development</a></li>


                                                </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheLearningHubNG/"><img src="images/soc/facebook1.png" height="32" width="32"></a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/LearningHubNG"><img src="images/soc/twitter1.png" height="32" width="32"></a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/thelearninghub_ng/"><img src="images/soc/instagram1.png" height="32" width="34"></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </nav>



                        <div  class ="about_wrap">              

                              <div class = "aboutus">
                                <header><h1>ABOUT US</h1></header>
                                <content>
                                    <p>
                                    The Learning Hub was established with the objective of developing and facilitating learning processes designed
                                         to maximise capacity building and self-development. We have extensive experience and appreciable competence
                                         in rendering quality services to our clients. The business and work environment changes quickly.

                                        The Learning Hub is an operating name and also the training and capacity building outfit of PACCENTER LTD. The
                                        Learning hub has been specifically dedicated as the Training and Consultancy services of PAC CENTER LTD. 
                                        PAC CENTER LTD is accredited by the Centre for Management Development (CMD) and is duly registered with the 
                                        Computer Professionals Registration Council of Nigeria (CPN).</p> 
                                    </content>

                              </div>

                              <div class = "aboutus">
                                <header><h1>OUR MISSION</h1></header>
                                <content>
                                    <p>
                                    To deliver skills and knowledge that signiﬁcantly increase our course participants' on-the-job productivity, 
                                    thereby enhancing their contributions to the goals of their organisation.
                                    </p> 
                                    </content>

                              </div>

                              <div class = "aboutus">
                                <header><h1>OUR VISION</h1></header>
                                <content>
                                    <p>
                                    To become the preferred partner to organisations and individuals by providing the most comprehensive
                                    professional and personal growth training.
                                    </p> 
                                    </content>

                              </div>

                              <div class = "aboutus">
                                        <header><h1>OUR CORE VALUES</h1></header>
                                        <content>
                                            <p>
                                            Through these values we create success:
                                            </p>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><span>L: Listen with empathy to problems</span></li>
                                                <li><span>E: Examine various opinions critically</span></li>
                                                <li><span>A: Acknowledge and discuss the diﬀerences and similarities</span></li>
                                                <li><span>R: Recommend the best solution</span></li>
                                                <li><span>N: Nonstop implementation and evaluation</span></li>
                                            </ul> 
                                            </content>

                              </div>

                              <a href="formpage.html" id = "button">Register Here</a>

                        </div>






                <div class ="right_image">
                      <img src = "images/gallery/about.png" width = "100%" alt "">
                </div>




                <div class = "bk">
                    <footer>
                           <div class = "footer_left">
                            <a>
                                <footer><p> &copy 2017 thelearningHub </p></footer>
                            </a>
                           </div>
                             <div class = "mobile_footer">
                                    <div class = "footer_right">
                                            <footer><p> We are social </p></footer>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class = "footer_social">        
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheLearningHubNG/"target="new" title="Facebook"> 
                                        <img class="socialicon" src="images/soc/facebook1.png" height="15" width="15"> 
                                    </a> 
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/LearningHubNG" target="new" title="Twitter"> 
                                        <img class="socialicon" src="images/soc/twitter1.png" height="15" width="15">
                                    </a> 
                                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/thelearninghub_ng/" target="new" title="Instagram"> 
                                        <img class="socialicon" src="images/soc/instagram1.png" height="15" width="15"> 
                                    </a>
                                    </div> 

                             </div>
                    </footer>

                </div>

            </div>   
</body>
```

Here is my css well commented:

The code responsible for the about us and right images is wrapped under a comment.

```
/***********About us************/
.about_wrap{
  width:40%;
  float:left;

}
.aboutus{
  padding-top: 20px;
  width:95%;

  padding-left:30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.aboutus h1{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}



ul li {
    color: #FFC213;
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

ul li span {
    color: black;
}



/******************Right images*****************/
.right_image{
  width:30%;

}

/******************event images*****************/


.imgitem{
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.image1, .image2, .image3{
float:left;
width:31%;
height: auto;
margin: 1%;
}



/******************gallery*****************/


.imgitem{
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
padding-left: 25px;
}

.img1, .img2, .img3, .img4{
float:left;
width:20%;
height: auto;
margin: 2%;
}

/***************contact**********/
.backg{
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:50%;
  background: white
}
.container{
  margin: 5%;
  padding:10%;
  background: #FFC213;
}
.container img{
  float:left;
  margin-right:6px;
}

.topcontent{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.middlecontent{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/**************form button*******************/

#container {
  background: white;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;

}

#contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea, #contact button[type="submit"] { font:400 12px/16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

#contact {
  background:#9B9B9B;
  padding:25px;
  margin:32px 35px;
}


fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  background:#FFF;
  margin:0 0 5px;
  padding:10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover, #contact input[type="email"]:hover, #contact input[type="tel"]:hover, #contact input[type="url"]:hover, #contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border:1px solid #AAA;
}

#contact textarea {
  height:100px;
  max-width:100%;
  resize:none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor:pointer;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  background:#FFf;
  color:#000000;
  margin:0 0 5px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background:#FFC213;
  -webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active { box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

#contact input:focus, #contact textarea:focus {
  outline:0;
  border:1px solid #999;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}

.error {
    color: black;
}

.success {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/****************Newsletter********************/
#get_email button[type="submit"] {
  cursor:pointer;
  width:100px;
  border:none;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  margin-top: -24px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/****************Registration********************/
#reg {
  background: white;
  width:90%;
  overflow:hidden;

}

#Course {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

#reg_contact{
  padding:25px;
  margin:50px;
}


#reg input[type="text"], #reg_contact input[type="email"], #reg_contact input[type="tel"], #reg_contact input[type="url"], #reg_contact textarea, #reg_contact button[type="submit"] { font:400 12px/16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

#reg {

  background:#ADADAD;
  padding:25px;
  margin:32px 35px;
}


fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#reg input[type="text"], #reg input[type="email"], #reg input[type="tel"], #reg input[type="url"], #reg textarea {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  background:#FFF;
  margin:0 0 5px;
  padding:10px;
}

#reg input[type="text"]:hover, #reg input[type="email"]:hover, #reg input[type="tel"]:hover, #reg input[type="url"]:hover, #reg textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border:1px solid #AAA;
}

#reg textarea {
  height:100px;
  max-width:100%;
  resize:none;
}

#reg button[type="submit"] {
  cursor:pointer;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  margin:0 0 5px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:15px;
}

#reg button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background:#FFC116;
  -webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#reg button[type="submit"]:active { box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

#reg input:focus, #reg textarea:focus {
  outline:0;
  border:1px solid #999;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color:#888;
}


/*****************Button*******************/

#button {
    background-color: #FFC213;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

/*****************Googlemap*******************/


.mymap{
  margin-left: 34px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  background-color: #FFC213; 
}


/********* footer ***********/
.footer_left{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 30px;
  color: white; 
}


.footer_right{
    float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.footer_social{  
  padding-right: 30px;
}



.footer_social a{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}



.mobile_footer{

  float:right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width :18%;
}


.bk{
    background:black;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the effort. I finally resolved it. What i did was to go to my footer and apply a width of 100% and float to left, this is to force it to the bottom of the page. Here are my edited code:

```
.bk{
  width: 100%;................apply width 100%...............
    background:black;
  float:left;.....................float left..............
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

float the first div to the left and apply a width in %

```
/******************Left images*****************/
.left_image{
  margin-top: 30px; 
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

float the second div to the right and give it a width.

```
.about_wrap{
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
}
```